# Xml add element node using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I would like to add an element node in my XML file using PHP. I can not get it right when I add it below root.
Please show me some clean code so that I understand how it works. Thank you!
My xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GameStore>

    <Game type="adventure">
    <TITLE>Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood</TITLE>
    <PUBLISHER>Ubisoft</PUBLISHER>
    </Game> 

    <Game type="adventure">
    <TITLE>Batman: Arkham Asylum</TITLE>
    <PUBLISHER>Eidos</PUBLISHER>
    </Game>

    </GameStore>
```

Comment: You want to add a new "Game"?

Comment: Yes. I want an example based on my xml structure. Tutorials that I find in google are complicated for my level. Thank you!

Comment: @user are you working with a specific XML library? If so, you should maybe post the code you have

Comment: Additionally, try and keep tag names lowercase and consistent through the XML document, you seem to have a mix of upper and lowercase tag names.

Comment: @user560411, please see [User systematically deleting and re-posting questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/user-systematically-deleting-and-re-posting-questions) (and note that your behaviour is not very much appreciated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a new game element, [simplexml](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) handles this pretty convenient. Example ($data is obviously your xml):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$game = $xml->addChild("game");
$game->addAttribute("type", "Game type");
$game->addChild("title", "Game title");
$game->addChild("publisher", "Game publisher");

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

This will append a "game" child to your xml. We then append two children (title, publisher) to game.

Comment: Thank you for that! I tried to replace the values (type, game type....) with variables but it is not working... Is there a way for this? My goal is to parse the vars through a form. Thanks again!

Comment: It should definetly work with variables. Are you sure that your variables are not empty?

Comment: I have changed this line
$game->addAttribute("type", "Game type");
to this
$game->addAttribute($var1, $var2);
but with error...

I have set values to my variables

Comment: The first argument to addAttribute is the name, you always want to pass "type" there. Try this, `$game->addAttribute("type", $var1);`.

Comment: @user instead of deleting questions after you have received your answer, please start marking as accepted the answer that best helped you.