# PHP appending data to xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have never really used XML before apart from very basic stuff so I'm still quite new to this. I am currently trying to append some data to my XML file. I have been using SimpleXML and this is what my data.xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 6.40 scan initiated Thu Aug  1 23:00:24 2019 as: nmap -p 21,22,30,69,80 -oX files/1oa6t0sb9e0uahiln7ismrvlre1564700424.xml google.com -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -p 21,22,30,69,80 -oX files/1oa6t0sb9e0uahiln7ismrvlre1564700424.xml google.com" start="1564700424" startstr="Thu Aug  1 23:00:24 2019" version="6.40" xmloutputversion="1.04">
<scaninfo type="connect" protocol="tcp" numservices="5" services="21-22,30,69,80"/>
<verbose level="0"/>
<debugging level="0"/>
<host starttime="1564700424" endtime="1564700426"><status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="74.125.193.101" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="google.com" type="user"/>
<hostname name="ig-in-f101.1e100.net" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="21"><state state="filtered" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ftp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="filtered" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="30"><state state="filtered" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="69"><state state="filtered" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="tftp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="http" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="1087" rttvar="2821" to="100000"/>
</host>
<runstats><finished time="1564700426" timestr="Thu Aug  1 23:00:26 2019" elapsed="1.23" summary="Nmap done at Thu Aug  1 23:00:26 2019; 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.23 seconds" exit="success"/><hosts up="1" down="0" total="1"/>
</runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

I have looked at this thread and tried to implement it as best as I can.

> [Xml add element node using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640707/xml-add-element-node-using-php)

So the code that I currently have that does not work is this. I am trying to add some data to the `host` child:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("files/test.xml");
$host = $xml->addChild("host");
$host->addAttribute("Somedata", "Some more data ");
$host->addChild("stuff ", "and stuff");


echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Any help in the right direction would be great

Comment: your question is really vague, _im trying to add some data to the host child_? you mean you're trying to add another batch of `<host>`? you're already on the right track, you've added another `<host>` in the parent node, now you need to continue build off of the structure

Comment: If you want to add data to the existing `<host>` element, then add it to the node rather than create a new host node - `$xml->host->addChild("stuff ", "and stuff");`